# 404 error on link button click to valid website address

Tags: asp.net

When a user clicks on this particular link button in question, I receive a 404 error in the browser. When I click the refresh button on the browser, the target website loads as normal. Any thoughts on what this might be? It's just a plain old .net link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkWhatAre" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF9999" 
                Style="text-decoration: none" CausesValidation="false"
                PostBackUrl="http://www.targetsite.com/">WHAT ARE?</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467188/why-would-an-aspx-file-return-404-the-page-cannot-be-found

Comment: @TimSchmelter, how do you find these links in such a short time. Do you remember them all? :)

Comment: My guess is you don't want to perform a cross page postback, you want to link to an external URL.  Could you just use a regular old HTML anchor tag here instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostBackUrl` causes page to perform POST request, not all target pages like it. If you simple mean to provide a navigation link you can use something like this instead:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkWhatAre" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF9999" 
     Style="text-decoration: none" 
     NavigateUrl="http://www.targetsite.com/">WHAT ARE?</asp:HyperLink>
```

"asp:HyperLink" is a server-side control, so you can still set all its properties in server-side code if needed. And it renders as a normal hyperlink - so it won't cause any problems redirecting.